# Apache2.4でDos攻撃あるいはDDos攻撃に備えるためのモジュールはなんですか？

Tags: apache

Apache2.4でサーバを構築しており、サードパーティのモジュールを使用してDos攻撃に備えようと考えております。

選択肢としては以下の３つが有力なようです。

1. mod_dosdetector
2. mod_evasive
3. mod_bw

ところが、以上３つのモジュールはApache2.4に対応していないという情報があり自分で確認したところ、確かにモジュールとして組み込むことはできるのですが（apachectl -Mで確認済）アクセス制限がなされません。

Apache2.4でDos攻撃にモジュールを使って備える場合には、どうすれば良いのでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

**mod_dosdetector** は Takayuki Miwa さんが Apache 2.4 版を [mod_dosdetector-fork](http://qiita.com/tkykmw/items/00f01708cfe1f45a73ad) としてフォークしていますね。

**mod_evasive** は RHEL/CentOS の場合 EPEL リポジトリからインストールすれば Apache 2.4 対応のようです。

提示されたもの以外で Slowloris 攻撃の対策に Lynis にサジェストされる **mod_qos** や、**ModSecurity**(mod_security)、**Fail2ban** などがあります。

その他、[Apache のドキュメント](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ja/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody)でDoS 攻撃対策のディレクティブとして言及されているものがあります。

- LimitRequestBody
- LimitRequestFields
- LimitRequestFieldSize
- LimitRequestLine
- RequestReadTimeout

Answer (score 1):

「DoS攻撃あるいはDDoS攻撃」と曖昧な表現でなく、[DDoS攻撃への2つの対策アプローチ](http://news.mynavi.jp/series/load_balancer/003/)等を参考に想定する攻撃方法を明確にしてください。その上でその攻撃がApacheプロセス内で対処可能であることが質問の前提条件になります。

一般的には、特にDDoS攻撃は、Webサーバーより手前で防御すると思います。